# How i extract lines that includes special keywords and print the lines to a seperate text file?

Tags: java, search, extract, bufferedreader

firsty i look for an anwer to my question but i dont find an exactly answer.
So i have many .log files (text documents) in different folders and subfolders. I have many, many .log files in different folders. If they are one of three keywords I want the complete line to one seperate text document with this criteria:

- i want to see the linenumber of the line in the .log file
- i want to see the path of line

I know that my code is not completed but i dont know how i continue.

And if i run my code, i see always blanks between the letters. why?

thanks for all helpfully answers!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // declare folder
    File folder = new File("path");

    if (!folder.exists()) {
        System.out.println("folder not existing");
    }
    listAllFilesForFolder(folder);
}

public static void listAllFilesForFolder(File folder) {
    // for each file in folder
    for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        // if file is another folder
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            // step into that folder recursively
            listAllFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            // its a file
            String filePath = fileEntry.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println("File is: " + filePath);
            parseFile(filePath);
        }
    }
}

public static void parseFile(String file) {
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {

        int LineCount = 0;
        // String line1 = "";

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        File folderError = new File("ErrorFolder");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename1.txt");
        // for each line in file
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {

            folderError.mkdir(); // create a folder in your current work space

            LineCount++;

            // print line
            System.out.println("line is: " + LineCount + " " + line);
            // TODO if line has an error, ... do something
            // read next line
            line = reader.readLine();

            out.println(line);
        }
        out.close();

        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils to do something as follow:

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.DirectoryFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;


public class SearchInFilesAndDirectory {

    private static int lineNumber = 0;

    private static final String FOLDER_PATH = "path_to_file";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File dir = new File(FOLDER_PATH);

        List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);

        for (File file : files) {

            if (file.isFile()) {

                try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        lineNumber++;
                        if (line.contains("word")) {
                            System.out.println("Keyword found in " + file.toPath() + " at line " + lineNumber + ".\n" + line.trim());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above will print out the path and line number, i.e.

```
Keyword found in /path/test/childFolder/test.txt at line 3.
3       Keyword test
Keyword found in /path/test/testFile.txt at line 5.
1       keyword ----
```

Comment: thx for ur answer but nevertheless it generates blanks... and it doesnt search in all folders and subfolders. it only search in just one folder... hmmm...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by (generates blanks) the above not writes to a folder, just prints out, it does search all of the subfolders if you specify the parent folder for FOLDER_PATH, the childFolder above is in test folder, maybe if you could put some actual folder structure and a sample file in your question that might help a bit more.

Comment: FileReader uses Java's platform default encoding, I have edited my answer so you can specify the encoding

Comment: thanks for your answer... now i have this errors:
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
 at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at SearchError.main(SearchError.java:31)

is it maybe because of my java version?

Comment: I don't think is java version maybe to do with the way we created BufferReader from Files, you can try changing to charset to ISO-8859-1 so it will be StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 if UTF_8 is not required.

Comment: I have already replied to errors: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 issue, what else? :)